# Remove paragraph that contains an specific word with sed

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sed, terminal

I need to remove the function that contains 'foobar' with sed command,
maybe using another default command. I will apply this to a lot of files.

```
main {
  engine "map" {
    func {
      var0 = foo
      border = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
      var1 = bar
    }
  }

  engine "map" {
    func {
      var0 = foo
      border = { 1, 2, 1, 2 }
      var1 = foobar
    }
  }

  engine "map" {
    func {
      var0 = foo
      border = { 3, 3, 1, 1 }
      var1 = bar
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` with null `RS`:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/foobar/' file
main {
  engine "map" {
    func {
      var0 = foo
      border = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
      var1 = bar
    }
  }

  engine "map" {
    func {
      var0 = foo
      border = { 3, 3, 1, 1 }
      var1 = bar
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the fast reply, but there is no way to do this with sed?

Comment: With sed it might be possible but it is easier with awk

Answer (score 0):

You could similarly use Perl:

`perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=""} print unless /foobar/' file`

`$/` is perl's record separator.  Setting it to `""` enables paragraph mode.